# Which model should I try first?

Tags: natural-language, lm

I think about appropriate modelling technique in the following task:

I have news texts (around 50K), and I have *news topics* made from the texts (250) which have various number of texts that made them up. I have already made topic modelling based on my data.

I wan't to carry hypothesis testing on whether frequency of certain tokens inside texts is signficantly linked to the topic size. For example, texts with frequent word 'blast' tend to form topics where there are 500 news texts involved on average, while frequent word 'politics' makes lesser topics.

Example of my data is on the picture.

[image]

I have experience with linear models, so first that comes to mind is inclusion of the frequence of the tokens of interest as regressors, whether observation is a news text:

```
> summary(lm(topic_size ~ freq_word1 + freq_word2, data = example_dat))

Call:
lm(formula = topic_size ~ freq_word1 + freq_word2, data = example_dat)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-250.02 -183.07  -11.38  162.57  371.67 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   256.02      45.61   5.613  5.9e-06 ***
freq_word1  -1182.85    3669.49  -0.322    0.750    
freq_word2  -5199.39    3804.66  -1.367    0.183    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 191.9 on 27 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0767,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.008307 
F-statistic: 1.121 on 2 and 27 DF,  p-value: 0.3405
```

However, I am not sure how to deal with the dependent variable "topic_size" which stays the same of hundreds of texts (which belong to one topic), and sometimes different topics have the same "topic_size".

**Is it related to mixed modelling, or a OLS linear model suffices my task?**

UPDATE (one word frequency VS. topic_size):

```
> mod <- lm(topic_size ~ word_freq, dat_train)
> summary(mod)

Call:
lm(formula = topic_size ~ word_freq, data = dat_train)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-232.95 -219.95    7.05  165.05  466.28 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   236.9471     0.9124 259.692  < 2e-16 ***
word_freq   -1901.5566   275.5316  -6.901 5.21e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 201.6 on 49998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0009517, Adjusted R-squared:  0.0009317 
F-statistic: 47.63 on 1 and 49998 DF,  p-value: 5.21e-12
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is topic_size and how does it relate to message_id? Are these messages with same topic size coming from the same text / news? Are you only interested in frequency of two words?

Comment: topic_size = count of news texts which hdescribe one topic (let it be new iphone). message_id is the ID of a news text which belongs to a topic with given topic_size . I want to loop over many possible tokens (and maybe include something like 100 tokens in a model). Do I clarify well?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to predict how many topics there will be, given the frequency of words 1 and 2? You are also concerned about your DV topic_size which has many similar values. Can you show us the 4 diagnostic plots of your model?

Comment: "you are trying to predict how many topics there will be", no, actually I am trying to predict what topic size will be (how many NEWS) given the word frequency in a news. "Can you show us the 4 diagnostic plots of your model" I haven't built any interesting linear model so far as I am not sure I can approach my data with OLS linear model and get accurate inference.

Comment: Can you show us the plot of the above linear model?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not save it (it was a sample of 30 news from 50 000 news), because it was just illustration of what I planned to do, not what I did for research.

Comment: Such a plot could help detect possible irregularities or problems.

Comment: OK, I created one simple model for one word and added stats to my question. The result is what I don't like not only because of bad stats, but also because this word in my opinion should increase topic size (word is "casualties").

Comment: Your model residuals are not good. You would have to do some diagnostics to correct these first (maybe a GLM could help). If this proves too hard you may want to look at other methods, which don't have as many assumption as linear models.

Comment: Thank you. I could try GLM indeed. If you create an answer I will accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your diagnostic plots it is not looking good for a regular OLS linear model. The residual plot is displaying a clear negative trend, the QQ plot is clearly not normal and in general the scale-location plot shows signs of what you would expect with a categorical variable having a strong influence on your results.

You've mentioned that a lot of times your DV topic size has very similar values and these are all integers, so maybe some sort of poisson regression may work better. Alternatively you may try your luck with a GLM, it is not immediately clear what would be a random effect in this case though, maybe some not-shown-above variable such as where the message /news was posted.

If all else fails a different model with less assumptions would probably work well too, especially if you have a pretty complex situation such as in your case. Regression random forests would be my first choice.